# UWP package submission

Tags: uwp, windows-10, windows-store-apps, xbox-one

I have a uwp app with a non flighted submission only targeting Xbox devices. Can I add a new package that only targets windows 10 desktop? I need two different packages targeting two different devices under the one product. I know this can't be achieved by in flight packages but wondering if there was another way of doing this.

Comment: During your app submission process, you could add different packages that target different device family under the same product.Could you mind to make your app private(This option is often used for beta testing) when you publish it to the Store?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. In manifest the default Name = Windows.Universal

so added

```
<Dependencies>
    <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Desktop" MinVersion="xxxxxxxx" MaxVersionTested="xxxxxxxxxx" />
  </Dependencies>
```

to App for desk top and

```
<Dependencies>
    <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Xbox" MinVersion="xxxxxx" MaxVersionTested="xxxxxxx" />
  </Dependencies>
```

to app for Xbox and when uploading to dev centre the devices are targeted by correct packages.